# i want to display data as json in html

Tags: html, json, api, flutter, postman

i'm using this [1](https://reqres.in/api/users) as api for my flutter app ( get data for FutureBuilder [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYE24.png))

i want to make page like it to could put my data in it ,I tired to put my data in html file and upload to
[3](https://www.awardspace.com/),it seems like it [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/475ML.png)

```html
<body>
    <div>{"page":1,"per_page":6,"total":12,"total_pages":2,"data":[{"id":1,"email":"george.bluth@reqres.in","first_name":"George","last_name":"Bluth","avatar":"https://reqres.in/img/faces/1-image.jpg"},{"id":2,"email":"janet.weaver@reqres.in","first_name":"Janet","last_name":"Weaver","avatar":"https://reqres.in/img/faces/2-image.jpg"},{"id":3,"email":"emma.wong@reqres.in","first_name":"Emma","last_name":"Wong","avatar":"https://reqres.in/img/faces/3-image.jpg"},{"id":4,"email":"eve.holt@reqres.in","first_name":"Eve","last_name":"Holt","avatar":"https://reqres.in/img/faces/4-image.jpg"},{"id":5,"email":"charles.morris@reqres.in","first_name":"Charles","last_name":"Morris","avatar":"https://reqres.in/img/faces/5-image.jpg"},{"id":6,"email":"tracey.ramos@reqres.in","first_name":"Tracey","last_name":"Ramos","avatar":"https://reqres.in/img/faces/6-image.jpg"}],"support":{"url":"https://reqres.in/#support-heading","text":"To keep ReqRes free, contributions towards server costs are appreciated!"}}</div>
  </body>
```

put when I use postman [5](https://www.postman.com/) it read link as HTML ,I want postman read it like json
to could use it in flutter

Comment: please add the code as text and links with proper alt text ,

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
            </script>
            <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      let data = {"page":1,"per_page":6,"total":12,"total_pages":2,"data":[{"id":1,"email":"george.bluth@reqres.in","first_name":"George","last_name":"Bluth","avatar":"https://reqres.in/img/faces/1-image.jpg"},{"id":2,"email":"janet.weaver@reqres.in","first_name":"Janet","last_name":"Weaver","avatar":"https://reqres.in/img/faces/2-image.jpg"},{"id":3,"email":"emma.wong@reqres.in","first_name":"Emma","last_name":"Wong","avatar":"https://reqres.in/img/faces/3-image.jpg"},{"id":4,"email":"eve.holt@reqres.in","first_name":"Eve","last_name":"Holt","avatar":"https://reqres.in/img/faces/4-image.jpg"},{"id":5,"email":"charles.morris@reqres.in","first_name":"Charles","last_name":"Morris","avatar":"https://reqres.in/img/faces/5-image.jpg"},{"id":6,"email":"tracey.ramos@reqres.in","first_name":"Tracey","last_name":"Ramos","avatar":"https://reqres.in/img/faces/6-image.jpg"}],"support":{"url":"https://reqres.in/#support-heading","text":"To keep ReqRes free, contributions towards server costs are appreciated!"}}
      data = JSON.stringify(data,null,4)
      $('pre').text(data)})
    </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <pre>Toggle between slide up and slide down for a p element</pre>
        </body>
    </html>
```

use pre tag to display as it will show the text in formatted structure, use script section to format the test. use JSON.stringify(data,null,intent) to format the data